# execute SET only for specific values?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$x = 5;
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE ' . $table. ' SET sort = sort + 1') ;
$stmt->execute();
```

How can I execute the query only for those values in `sort` column which are equal or higher than `$x` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add it to as where statement:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE ' . $table. ' SET sort = sort + 1 where sort >= ?') ;
$stmt->bind(1, $x)
```